# Got JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process

Tags: react-native

After upgrading from react-native 0.26 to 0.29 (and running react-native upgrade), I'm getting the following error in the android debugger:

```
Got JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process
```

And this error message in the android emulator

```
java.lang.RunTimeException: ReferenceError: can't find variable process
 (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle (...)
```

I haven't changed any of my app javascript since upgrading, and everything ran without errors before so I'm assuming the problem isn't in the javascript, but rather the change of react versions has removed the 'process' variable?

Even loading an empty index file (a single react component that does nothing) still results in the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
java.lang.RuntimeException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process
```

Fixed by upgrading the React to the latest compatible version, 15.2.1 in my case:

```
npm i react@15.2.1 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, it turns out my problem was that I didn't stop and restart the packager after upgrading react-native.