# React Native Android 0.30 Can't find variable process

Tags: react-native

After having upgraded from 0.27.2 to 0.30 (I've even tried 0.31.0-rc.0), I get the following Error on my Android device (both simulator and my device):

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
java.lang.RuntimeException:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable:
process (http://...&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:2448)`

See attachment.[image]

Any idea why that could happen?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is found here:
[Got JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446937/got-js-exception-referenceerror-cant-find-variable-process)

You simply have to update `react` to `15.2.1`.

Comment: I've run into the same Problem with react 15.4.1. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Still experiencing this issue with React 16.2.